# Python regex group() appends 'None'

Tags: python, regex

I have simple regex for parsing this string:

```
rawresp0 = """<response>
<comment>Привет.</comment>
</response>"""
```

I need to get:

> Привет.

But the code below for some reason returns:

```
Привет.
None
```

Whats wrong

```
def pars_resp(text):
    reg = re.compile(ur'(?<=<comment>).+(?=</comment>)', re.U)
    print reg.search(unicode(text, "UTF-8")).group(0)

print pars_resp(rawresp0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. Well, except the

```
print pars_resp(rawresp0)
```

The function `pars_resp` returns `None`. Remove that print statement so the last line is:

```
pars_resp(rawresp0)
```

and it will work.

*Edit*:

Alternatively, let the function return the string you want to print:

```
def pars_resp(text):
    reg = re.compile(ur'(?<=<comment>).+(?=</comment>)', re.U)
    return reg.search(unicode(text, "UTF-8")).group(0)

print pars_resp(rawresp0)
```

This is often more useful, because you can now do other things with the string you extracted than print it.

Answer (score 1):

You have two prints. The first one prints the result of your search and the second prints the return value of `pars_resp`, which is `None` since you don't return something.

Change it either to

```
def pars_resp(text):
    reg = re.compile(ur'(?<=<comment>).+(?=</comment>)', re.U)
    print reg.search(unicode(text, "UTF-8")).group(0)

pars_resp(rawresp0)
```

or to

```
def pars_resp(text):
    reg = re.compile(ur'(?<=<comment>).+(?=</comment>)', re.U)
    return reg.search(unicode(text, "UTF-8")).group(0)

print pars_resp(rawresp0)
```

and it will print what you want.